# How can I write a shared library with Qt that wraps another library?

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, wrapper

I'm trying to create a Qt shared library that wraps a lower level C library, meaning that I don't want that C library's header file to be accessed by the calling code that links to the library.

I'm following the steps [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html), which seem to be straightforward.  I've constructed a SUBDIRS project in QtCreator.  The library project builds fine, all classes and C functions are marked with the macro that expands to Q_DECL_EXPORT.  The library defines a some headers that I want to include in the app project.  The problem here is that when I include one of those headers, the chain is followed down to the C library header that is included, and at which point the application project fails to build since it can't find that header.

Qt's documentation specifically points out this issue, but is kind of vague about how to solve it.

```
#include <footronics/device.h>

 class MyDevice {
 private:
     FOOTRONICS_DEVICE_HANDLE handle;
 };
```

> When deploying the library, there should be no dependency to the internal headers footronics/device.h or ui_widget.h.

So, how can I avoid the headers that I'm including from the library, from implicitly including the headers from the C library that I'm wrapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only use pointers or references to classes of the shared library you can use [Forward Declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

```
class FooTronicsDevice;

class MyDevice {
private:
    FooTronicsDevice* _device;
}
```

The compiler doesn't need to know the structure of the class in order to define a pointer (or a reference).

If this isn't possible, you can use the [Pointer to Implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) idiom which is suggested in the Qt Documentation.
This basically means you separate the implementation from your public interface.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that I could just forward declare any types that were necessary from the C library, but I was thinking that there was actually some kind of setting or macro that was necessary to avoid this stuff. Of course the simplest solution is the right one. Thanks very much.